# Postgresql: select from view multiple times?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query wrapped in a view that returns a subset of user ids I want to then use in other queries. The problem I am trying to solve is to avoid to run that view query every time I want to then run other queries that use that view.

Is there a way to run it, to get the user ids I need from it, and then use that result to run other 3 queries I need to run (for example) that would then use the user ids returned in that view to join on other tables?

So now I have something like this:

```
with user_ids as (
               select u.id
                from "user" u
                inner join .....
    )
select count(*)
from user_ids
inner join table_a on ....
```

I then want to run three more queries using the `user_ids` view without having to run that view query again.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could put it into a (TEMP) VIEW.

Comment: that worked great. I wasn't aware of temporary views. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I used TEMPORARY VIEW.

Looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW user_ids as
(

select u.id
from "user" u
inner join ...
);
```

then this:

query 1:

```
select count(*)
from user_ids
inner join ...
```

query 2:

```
select count(*)
from user_ids
inner join ...
```

....